# Create action always creates two identical table entries instead of one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, rails-activerecord

I have a create action in my ProductsController (the params come from a form in my view):

```
def create
  vendor = @current_vendor
  product = Product.create(:name => params[:product][:name])
  vendor.products << product
  vendor.belongings.create(:product_id => product.id, :count => params[:belonging][:count], :detail => params[:belonging][:detail])
  if vendor.save
    flash[:notice] = "Produkt hinzugefügt!"
    redirect_back_or_default root_url
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

1. It creates a variable "vendor", which stores the currently logged-in vendor (Authlogic)
2. A new Product is created (the product name is from the input field in the form) and stored in the variable "product"
3. The "product" is being connected to the current vendor
4. In the belongings table, additional informations to the product are being stored
5. it saves the whole thing

It's a many-to-many relationship throught the belongings table.

**My problem is, the create action always creates the product twice!**

Thanks for your help! :)

My console log when I create a new object through my form is:

```
Started POST "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-15 20:40:26 +0200
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lNk/qQMP0xhlCuGgHtU+d5NEvIlCFcPSKB0FxDZH0zY=", "product"=>{"name"=>"Erdbeeren"}, "belonging"=>{"count"=>"20", "detail"=>"Rot"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveRecord::Base#with_scope and #with_exclusive_scope are deprecated. Please use ActiveRecord::Relation#scoping instead. (You can use #merge to merge multiple scopes together.). (called from current_vendor_session at /Users/reto_gian/Desktop/dici/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11)
  Vendor Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."persistence_token" = '04f75db0e2ef108ddb0ae1be1da167536d47b4d79c60ecb443ad2ea5717ecd752388e581f9379746568c72372be4f08585aa5581915b1be64dc412cded73a705' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 15 Sep 2013 18:40:26 UTC +00:00], ["name", "Erdbeeren"], ["updated_at", Sun, 15 Sep 2013 18:40:26 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "belongings" ("created_at", "product_id", "updated_at", "vendor_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 15 Sep 2013 18:40:26 UTC +00:00], ["product_id", 7], ["updated_at", Sun, 15 Sep 2013 18:40:26 UTC +00:00], ["vendor_id", 1]]
   (0.9ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "belongings" ("count", "created_at", "detail", "product_id", "updated_at", "vendor_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["count", "20"], ["created_at", Sun, 15 Sep 2013 18:40:26 UTC +00:00], ["detail", "Rot"], ["product_id", 7], ["updated_at", Sun, 15 Sep 2013 18:40:26 UTC +00:00], ["vendor_id", 1]]
   (0.9ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 5.1ms)
```

Comment: Try `Product.new` instead of `Product.create`

Comment: why this line: `vendor.products << product`?  that might be the culprit

Comment: The problem persists even if I make this changes... Maybe you're interested in my console log when I create a new object in my form. I'll update my post and include the log. :)

Comment: @dax I assume this makes the connection between the vendor and the newly created product, maybe this is the fault

Comment: will add this as answer - I think it's likely the issue

Comment: Thanks @dax I removed the line and it works like a charm! Please write this as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem could be in the line

```
vendor.products << product
```

this is adding the variable `product` (which is `Product.create(:name => params[:product][:name])` to `vendor.products` a second time - which is unnecessary and likely the source of your problem